# Warning: curl_setopt_array(): Unable to create temporary file. - Windows PHP / Guzzle

Tags: php, curl, temp

When I run HTTP Requests with Guzzle (Windows PHP CLI) I keep getting this error message. After extensive research on the net I can't find a reason. Do you have any advice?

```
Warning: curl_setopt_array(): Unable to create temporary file. in C:\wamp\www\tools\inc\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php on line 66
PHP Warning:  curl_setopt_array(): Unable to create temporary file. in C:\wamp\www\tools\inc\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php on line 66
```

php -v:

`PHP 7.4.32 (cli) (built: Sep 28 2022 18:22:17) ( NTS Visual C++ 2017 x64 )`

php.ini:

```
;sys_temp_dir = 
upload_tmp_dir =
```

CLI - php -r "echo sys_get_temp_dir();"

```
C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Temp
```

<- I also tried to set this path with "" in sys_temp_dir & upload_tmp_dir - but nothing changed

PHP binary location (PATH variable): C:\src\php

**C:\wamp\www\tools\inc\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php**

```
public function create(RequestInterface $request, array $options): EasyHandle //Zeile 41
{
    if (isset($options['curl']['body_as_string'])) {
        $options['_body_as_string'] = $options['curl']['body_as_string'];
        unset($options['curl']['body_as_string']);
    }

    $easy = new EasyHandle;
    $easy->request = $request;
    $easy->options = $options;
    $conf = $this->getDefaultConf($easy);
    $this->applyMethod($easy, $conf);
    $this->applyHandlerOptions($easy, $conf);
    $this->applyHeaders($easy, $conf);
    unset($conf['_headers']);

    // Add handler options from the request configuration options
    if (isset($options['curl'])) {
        $conf = \array_replace($conf, $options['curl']);
    }

    $conf[\CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION] = $this->createHeaderFn($easy);
    $easy->handle = $this->handles
        ? \array_pop($this->handles)
        : \curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($easy->handle, $conf); //Zeile 66

    return $easy;
} //Zeile 69
```

Comment: what is in lines 60-70  of `C:\wamp\www\tools\inc\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php` ?

Comment: add a var_dump there, ```var_dump($conf);curl_setopt_array($easy->handle, $conf);``` what do you get?